# for loop (conditional) and logical s operation in python

Tags: python

I am trying to combine for loop and logical operation and as below and running into compilation error.

Any inputs on how to fix this?

```
File "test.py", line 36
    for ((num in list) and (num not in handled_list)):
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You can't use a conditional expression in a `for` statement like that.

Comment: `list` is the name of the built-in function `list()`, so best not to use it as a variable.

Comment: You can use `while` with conditionals. `for` will only work with iterators and sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do this using sets:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [3, 5]
>>> for num in set(a) ^ set(b):
...     print num
...
1
2
4
```

Answer (score 2):

The `for` statement doesn't support that sort of syntax.  The syntax is just `for item in iterable` --- you don't get to specify conditions.  Specify your conditions inside the loop:

```
for num in list:
    if num in handled_list:
        continue
    # Do what you want with the elements in list but not in handled_list
```

Or precreate a list (or other iterable) that has just what you want to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` statement doesnt allow for the conditionals you're trying to do.

You can however check for presence:

Assuming the following:

```
nums = [1,2,3,5,4]
handled_list  = [12,3,5,23,4]
num = 2

if ((num in nums) and (num not in handled_list)):
    print "hello, i did find the number in nums but not in handled list"
```

The iteration still takes place in the `if` statement but doesn't allow for access of each iterated element.

Comment: `list` is a poor choice for a variable name.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you, i just wrote it straight of his question.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to be as tight on your example as possible, this is a solution:

```
my_list = [1, 3, 5]
handled_list = [3]

for n in [num for num in my_list if num not in handled_list]:
    print n
```

It is strongly recommended to avoid redefinition of built-ins, like you seem to do with "list".

Comment: This one is the most generalizable : the accepted answer only works due to combining two conditions into one via the bitwise operation

Answer (score 0):

`for` statements cannot be used that way. A simple way to accomplish what you want to do may be the following.

```
>>> for num in listOne:
        if num not in listTwo:
           # Do Something
```

Also, `list` is an inbuilt object, it'd be good if you didn't use that as a variable name.